# My final render is completely different from my viewport window

Tags: rendering

I know this may be an easy fix, and I'm just not looking hard enough, but how am I supposed to have my final render look completely identical to my viewport display? I have taken the time to set up a semi-realistic glossy texture for my eye, but every time I render it, no matter which settings I tamper with, my final render's texture looks like paper. Any possible fix would be appreciated.

[image: As you can see, the final render is not as expected.]

Comment: It looks like you're using one of the built-in HDRIs (`interior.exr`) for the viewport shading (*Scene World* is disabled). You will have to setup your environment texture for the world, which is used for the final render. The viewport shading options are only for a preview/look dev.

Comment: Thank you! Problem solved.